# How to invoke docker:publishLocal as a test dependency in sbt

Tags: sbt

My project uses sbt-native-packager's Docker plugin to generate Docker containers.  I'd like containerization to occur before running unit tests.  (The command to do this is 'sbt docker:publishLocal')

How can I wire in my Build.scala file so that the test task in sbt will run docker:publishLocal first, before its normal test activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(Keys.test in Test) <<= (Keys.test in Test) dependsOn (publishLocal in Docker)
```

Comment: sbt didn't recognize 'docker' in the above, yet the manual command I use in sbt is indeed docker:publishLocal, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.  I have this: ```lazy val cluster = project.in(file("cluster")).settings(test <<= (test in Test) dependsOn publishLocal)```  This will do a non-docker publishLocal, which is something, but not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The sbt 1.8.2 version of this would be

```
Test / test := {(Test / test).dependsOn(Docker / publishLocal).value}
```